# Remove an initial part of a string in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

I have a variable storing "ping_abc", how do I remove the "ping_" part to get just "abc"?

My approach:
variable 'test' stores "ping_abc"

I tried:

```
echo ${test:0:4}
```

But this is giving me:

```
Bad : modifier in $ (4), error
```

Approach on suggested answer by @Yaron:

```
set test = "ping_abc"
echo test | awk -F_ '{print $2}'
echo ping_abc | awk -F_ '{print $2}'
```

o/p:

```
        //blankspace
 abc
```

Why does the test variable not get truncated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tcsh`, you can use "history style" `:` modifiers in parameter expansions:

```
xenial-vm:~> set test = ping_abc
xenial-vm:~> echo $test
ping_abc
xenial-vm:~> echo ${test:s/ping_//}
abc
xenial-vm:~>
```

See for example [History Substitution](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/History_substitution.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` in the following way:

```
echo ping_abc | awk -F_ '{print $2}'
```

which result with:

```
abc
```

Explanation about `awk` parameters:

- -F_ - use _ for the input field separator
- print $2 - print the second field in the input record

More info [man awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)

Comment: Showing me syntax error.

Comment: awk: cmd. line:1: printf $2
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error   with ^ pointing to p(rint)

Comment: @AmbareeshSJ  I've edit my answer to support both `bash` and `tcsh`. for `tcsh` you should use the following: echo ping_abc | awk -F_ '{print $2}'